# Dwarves take a long time to decide to do tasks, when they usually take a short time to decide to do them

Tags: dwarf-fortress

So, Whenever I designated random things in the past, My dwarves would do it almost immediately.

Now Whenever I play the game, The dwarves remain idle for around 3 minutes before they actually start working. I don't like how my Brewer is taking so long between tasks.

How could I fix this?

Comment: Um. Do you have a question?

Comment: Let me edit this.

Comment: There, You can review it now.

Comment: Sorry, but you need to add more details to your question. Like: what is the Brewer doing instead of brewing? Why do you have one Brewer instead of letting anyone brew? What other tasks are competing with brewing and having higher priority?